# adjust ajax partial view items in foreach in main page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have PartialViewResult that i need to adjust the foreach loop in the main view (id) to the foreach loop (id) in the partial view .
i have a list of items(name="QuettaOffer")in the main view ,and each item has a list of items in the partial view (name="QToSellers").
i need to loop and display each item  in the partial view to his father item.i dotn have this 2 entireties in the same view because the user can submit/edit items in the partial view (So save page load)

code:Main page controller

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> check(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null) return NotFound ();

        var compareOffers =
            await _context.QuettaOffers

                //ToDo copy the value of the last data to submit  >> .Where(a=>aLASTDATETOS) ?  
                .Where(a => a.QuettaReqId == id)
                .Include(a => a.QToSellers)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.SellerAns)
                .Include(s => s.Supplayer)
                .ToListAsync ();
        return View(compareOffers);
    }
```

code main page view :

```
@model IEnumerable<BizTov.Models.QuettaOffer>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
/// data items
<div class="data">
//here goes the partial view
</div>
}
```

code partial view controller :

```
 public async Task<PartialViewResult> _QtoSelelr(int QuoteId)
    {
        var questions = await _context.qToSellers.Where
                (b => b.QuoteId == QuoteId)
            .ToListAsync ();
        return PartialView((IEnumerable<QToSeller>) questions);
    }
```

code partial view

```
 @model IEnumerable<BizTov.Models.Features.QToSeller>
     should be @foreach (var Qitem in Model.Where(id=>id.QuettaOfferId== @item.QuettaOfferId))
        @foreach (var Qitem in Model)
        {
            //items..
        }
```

code ajax :

```
$.ajax({url: '/Request/_QtoSelelr',
                            dataType: 'html',
                            contentType: 'application/html;charset:utf-8',
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: {
                                QuoteId: reId
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('.data').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();
                            }
                            });
```

I hope my Q is clear

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i need to have QuettaOfferId from table QToSeller within QuettaOfferId  from table QuettaOffers

Comment: Hard to visiualize. What's the current output?

Comment: are have problem in "How call all of partial fro QuoteId by loop in jquery "? i think you code in asp is correct but some javascript is mised

Comment: im trying to embed the FK in partial to key on main . what JS part did i missed ?